# How to append to the file using python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

```
mean_temp = open("mean_temp.txt",'a+')
mean_temp = mean_temp.write("Rio de Janeiro,Brazil,30.0,18.0\n")
mean_temp.seek(0)
mean_temps = mean_temp.read()
print(mean_temps)
```

I'm not able to append the text in the file instead it is giving the count in *mean_temp* where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mean_temp.write` returns written bytes count, so:

```
mean_temp = open("mean_temp.txt", "a+")
mean_temp.write("Rio de Janeiro,Brazil,30.0,18.0\n")
mean_temp.seek(0)
mean_temps = mean_temp.read()
print(mean_temps)
```

Also, I recommend using the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) here:

```
with open("mean_temp.txt", "a+") as mean_temp:
    mean_temp.write("Rio de Janeiro,Brazil,30.0,18.0\n")
    mean_temp.seek(0)
    data = mean_temp.read()
    print(data)
```